# WPF привязка DataContext к полю родительского DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть у меня главная форма, у нее в `DataContext` указана модель этой формы. В этой модели есть свойство, ссылающееся на другую модель. Я хочу определенный элемент формы привязать к контексту той самой модели, что находится в свойстве. Я пробовал писать `DataContext={Binding anotherModel}`, это не помогает. даже если использовать `Mode=TwoWay`.

Модель:

```
public static MainWindow instance;           // статическая ссылка на объект MainWindow

private static MyClass _anotherModel = null; // внутренне хранилище значения
public static MyClass anotherModel           // обработчик изменения значения
{
    get => _anotherModel;
    set
    {
        if (_anotherModel == value) return;
        _anotherModel = value;
        instance.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(instance, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("anotherModel "));
    }
}
```

Элемент формы:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Tabs" DataContext="{Binding anotherModel, Mode=TwoWay}"></TabControl>
```

Когда я проверяю `DataContext` этого элемента через [динамическое визуальное дерево](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/mt270227.aspx), то там написано `BindingExpression` и его нельзя просмотреть.

**Интересный факт:** Если перед инициализацией компонентов присвоить этому свойству ссылку на модель, то в инспекторе оно будет отображено и его можно просмотреть.

Comment: А почему свойство статическое?

Comment: `Mode=TwoWay` - эта детектива разрешает не только читать но и писать переменную, прямого отношения к вашей проблеме не имеет.

Comment: Проблема автора в том, что он пытается привязать статическое свойство способом, который подходит только для экземплярных. К тому же какой-то костыль с `static instance`пытается прикрутить, который не сработает.

Comment: У меня свойство статическое, потому что мне нужно получать его из других форм. У меня так же есть статический `ObservableCollection`, но привязка к нему выполняется успешно.

Comment: Вы, вроде, и тег MVVM поставили, но фактически у вас данные во вьюхе, отсюда и костыли ваши со статикой. А не работает это по той причине, что вызывая `instance.PropertyChanged?.Invoke` вы говорите фреймворку, что у вас обновилось свойство `"anotherModel "` в экземпляре `instance`, но в нем нет такого свойства, оно статическое и не принадлежит никакому экземпляру.

Comment: Значит надо отправлять `null`?

Comment: Нет, это тоже не сработает. Возможно надо иметь статическое событие `PropertyChanged` (или `anotherModelChanged`), но не уверен, т.к. никогда не пробовал. Вообще здесь статика не нужна, не устану это повторять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда я сделал свойство нестатическим и стал вызывать `PropertyChanged` непосредственно из самой модели (вместо того, чтобы вызывать его из `instance`), все заработало.

Было:

```
private static MyClass _anotherModel = null;
public static MyClass anotherModel
{
    get => _anotherModel;
    set
    {
        if (_anotherModel == value) return;
        _anotherModel = value;
        instance.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(instance, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("anotherModel"));
    }
}
```

Стало:

```
private MyClass _anotherModel = null;
public MyClass anotherModel
{
    get => _anotherModel;
    set
    {
        if (_anotherModel == value) return;
        _anotherModel = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("anotherModel"));
    }
}
```